# Spring not rolled back with a RuntimeException

Tags: java, spring

```
<!-- 引入外部JDBC配置信息 -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:JDBC.properties" />
<!-- 配置C3P0连接池: -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${DriverClass}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${URL}" />
    <property name="user" value="${USER}" />
    <property name="password" value="${PASSWORD}" />
    <!-- 其他配置 -->
    <!--初始化时获取三个连接，取值应在minPoolSize与maxPoolSize之间。Default: 3 -->
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="3"></property>
    <!--连接池中保留的最小连接数。Default: 3 -->
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="3"></property>
    <!--连接池中保留的最大连接数。Default: 15 -->
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5"></property>
    <!--当连接池中的连接耗尽的时候c3p0一次同时获取的连接数。Default: 3 -->
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3"></property>
    <!-- 控制数据源内加载的PreparedStatements数量。如果maxStatements与maxStatementsPerConnection均为0，则缓存被关闭。Default: 
        0 -->
    <property name="maxStatements" value="8"></property>
    <!--maxStatementsPerConnection定义了连接池内单个连接所拥有的最大缓存statements数。Default: 0 -->
    <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection" value="5"></property>
    <!--最大空闲时间,1800秒内未使用则连接被丢弃。若为0则永不丢弃。Default: 0 -->
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="1800"></property>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate的相关信息 -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <!-- 注入连接池 -->
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <!-- 配置Hibernate的其他的属性 -->
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <!-- 配置Hibernate的映射文件 -->
    <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath:*.hbm.xml">
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- 事务管理: -->
<!-- 事务管理器 -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- 配置事务通知属性 -->
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <!-- 定义事务传播属性 -->
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="insert*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="edit*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="add*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="new*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="set*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="remove*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="delete*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="change*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        <tx:method name="get*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="find*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="load*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* com.fjx.service.*.*(..))"
        id="servicePointcut" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="servicePointcut" />
</aop:config>

<bean id="roleDao" class="com.fjx.dao.RoleDao">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="roleService" class="com.fjx.service.RoleService">
    <property name="roleDao" ref="roleDao"></property>
</bean>
```

roleService文件如下:

```
public class RoleService {
    private RoleDao roleDao;

    public void save(Role role){
        roleDao.save(role);
    }

    public void setRoleDao(RoleDao roleDao) {
        this.roleDao = roleDao;
    }
}
```

junit测试类如下:

```
@Test
    public void saveTest(){
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        RoleService roleService = (RoleService) applicationContext.getBean("roleService");
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setRname("11");
        role.setRdescription("1111");

    int i = 1/0;
    roleService.save(role);
    Role role1 = new Role();
    role1.setRname("11");
    role1.setRdescription("1111");
    roleService.save(role1);
}
```

There is an Exception, but the role is saved successfully.It is not rollbacked, i can not find out the question...

Comment: Hi Demon Jun, and welcome to Stack Overlow. You need to edit your question a little, as some of the markup is not working on the code blocks - remember, every code block should be indented with four spaces and separated by blank lines from the blocks of prose or code above and below.

Comment: I can not find out the question as well.... Should be closed - unclear what you're asking.